# XHR doesnt send json object

Tags: javascript, express, xmlhttprequest

I have client - server express app. Im trying to send an XHR request from frontend to my controller, while passing json data. My frontend code looks like this:

```
function handle_login(){
    var username_field = document.getElementById('input_username');
    var pass = document.getElementById('input_password');
    if(username_field.value!=null)console.log(username_field.value);
    console.log(pass.value);


    //window.location.href = "/loginAttempt/"+username.value+"-"+pass.value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/home_pogled"; 
     xhr.open("GET", url, true);
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
             var data = {
            username : username_field.value,
            password : pass.value
        }
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        xhr.send(json);

        xhr.onload = function() {//ob uspesnem odgovoru
            var responseText = xhr.responseText;
            //console.log("Backend server response -" +responseText);
            // uporabi odgovor
        };
        xhr.onerror = function() {
          console.log('There was an error!');
        };


}
```

I can send the request and i'm certain that data is written to the json object prior to sending it, but when i do consonle.log(req.body) in my controller upor receiving the request the body is empty "{}", where is should havec ontained the username and password values in a json objkect. What am i missing?

Comment: Where exactly are you doing `consonle.log(req.body)`, it doesn't appear in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

**Client Side:**

We can't send object in GET method, it should be query params like below snippet

```
let url = `/home_pogled?username=${username_field.value}&password=${pass.value}`; 

xhr.open('GET', url);
```

**Server side (express app):**

In express js, we can get the query params in [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

`let username = req.query.username;
 let password = req.query.password`